# PyTorch - get list of sums of 2D tensors in 3D tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 3D tensor consisting of 2D tensors, e. g.:

```
t = torch.tensor([[[0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0]],

                  [[0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0]],

                  [[0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0]]
                  ])
```

I need a list or tensor of sums of those 2D tensors, e. g.: `sums = [3, 3, 3]`. So far I have:

```
sizes = [torch.sum(t[i]) for i in range(t.shape[0])]
```

I think this can be done with PyTorch only, but I've tried using `torch.sum()` with all possible dimensions and I always get sums over the individual fields of those 2D tensors, e. g.:

```
[[0, 0, 3],
[0, 3, 0],
[3, 0, 0]]
```

How can this be done in PyTorch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it at once by passing dims as tuple.

```
t.sum(dim=(0,1))
tensor([3, 3, 3])
```

or for list

```
t.sum(dim=(0,1)).tolist()
[3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If understood your problem correctly, this should do the job:

```
t.sum(0).sum(1).tolist()
```

Output:
`[3, 3, 3]`